# find action not working for specific search

Tags: bash, arch-linux, find, manjaro

I'm trying to use the `find` command to list the size of a certain set of files but am getting no output. The command I use is:

```
find POD -type f -name *.mp3 -or -name *.ogg -ls
```

Which produces no output. While:

```
find POD -type f -name *.mp3 -or -name *.ogg
```

does produce output, I've also tried the actions:

```
-printf "%p %k KB\n"
-exec ls -ls '{}' \;
-print0
```

but all of these give no output. When I use any of these actions with a different expression e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p %k KB\n"
```

I also get the expected output. Does anybody have any idea what the problem is?
I'm running:

```
Linux irimi 3.10.37-1-MANJARO #1 SMP Mon Apr 14 20:56:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

aka an up to date Manjaro linux distribution. The shell I use is: `/bin/bash` version `4.3.8(1)-release`.

The content of my `SHELLOPTS` environment variable is:

```
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

my `BASHOPTS` environment variable is:

```
cdspell:checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:dotglob:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:nocaseglob:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
```

Again any help on trying to debug this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trap with the *and/or* keywords on `find`. `or` applied to all the following parameters including the action (`-ls` in your example). `and` expressions without `or` (or attached with `and`) are evaluated in reading order with a final stop as false. There is no `implicit ()`.

So the command `find POD -type f -name *.mp3 -or -name *.ogg -ls` means,

- search (starting from the POD directory) for files 
  --- if no file found : STOP
- else (file found) check pattern matching `*.mp3`
  --- if pattern match : STOP !  (because `OR` applied from here and only if the previous command failed (but only the previous command, not the previous groups of command)

and because you add an execute statement (`-ls`, `-exec`, `-print`....) in the command line there is no implicit `-print` command and so nothing to execute if 1) all the conditions of 1) are true (file and pattern matched). If you remove the last `-ls` there an implicit `-print` distributed at the end of each condition branches.

- else if pattern didn't match search for anything (file/directory) matching the pattern `*.ogg` and list them (the `-ls` is not a condition command, it's executed only if the previous command/test "pattern `*.ogg` is true). But because of 1), 2) is evaluated only for NON mp3 files. If you don't have `.ogg` files you don't see anything.

**Solution 1**  repeat the execution command in each logical branch

```
   find POD -type f -name "*.mp3" -ls -or -name "*.ogg" -ls
```

**Solution 2** add (shell protected) parenthesis

```
   find POD -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -ls -or -name "*.ogg" \) -ls
```

**Note**  you should protect the patterns to avoid shell pattern evaluation in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the evaluation order (lack of explicit precedence) e.g. if

```
-name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' -ls
```

then if `-name '*.ogg'` evaluates false, the `ls` action is not executed. You can get the behaviour you expect by grouping your OR expressions using parentheses - for example, if

```
$ ls tests
file1.mp3  file2.mp3  file3.mp3
```

Then

```
$ find tests \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print
tests/file3.mp3
tests/file1.mp3
tests/file2.mp3
```

whereas

```
$ find tests -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' -print
```

produces no output. Note that

```
$ find tests -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg'
```

is a special case because it is implicitly treated as

```
$ find tests \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print
```

Also note that it's good practice to quote or escape shell globs in a `find` command to prevent the shell from expanding them - see the `NON-BUGS` section of the find manpage.