# find only finds files when no explicit action is passed

Tags: find

I'm finding that some find commands I enter, ignore a lot of files, and only seem to work properly* if I do not pass an action at the end of the command.

I will use the following command as the base for this question:
`find . -depth -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe'`

Real example:
`find . -depth -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' -or -name 'f*.xml' -or -name '*.html' -or -name '*.jar' -or -name '*.mat' -or -name '*.pyc' -or -name '*_dll' -or -name '*.class' -or -name '*.DS_Store' -or -name '*.dll' -or -name '*.dex'`

The base command on its own gives plenty of output, but the following command does nothing*:
`find . -depth -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' -delete`

Similarly, this command, though it should be identical to the base command, gives no output*:
`find . -depth -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' -print`

Or even*:
`find . -depth -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' -exec echo {} \;`

Am I missing something about how find works?

I'm using GNU find version 4.8.0.

*By "work properly", I mean that if I run the base command, I will find *all* matching files, but with any explicit action, only some consistent subset will be found. This means that if I pass `-delete`, that subset will be gone, and no explicit actions will find any of the remaining files. Reverting to the base command will find them again.

Comment: How do I reply to suggestions that my question is a duplicate? The other question asks a very different question, though one of the answer indeed also answers my question. (I even linked to it in my answer!)

Answer (score 0):

## Brackets

Apparently, actions become part of the or-expression, and only work for one of the branches, while removing the implicit print for all of them. ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129413/26356))

The solution then, is to write the expression as follows, which encloses the or branches and ensures the action is not applied to just one branch:
`find . -depth \( -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' -or -name 'f*.xml' -or -name '*.html' -or -name '*.jar' -or -name '*.mat' -or -name '*.pyc' -or -name '*_dll' -or -name '*.class' -or -name '*.DS_Store' -or -name '*.dll' -or -name '*.dex' \)`

Or the short form:
`find . -depth \( -name '*.elf' -or -name '*.exe' \)`

I'm still posting this question (plus the answer) because I couldn't find the right search terms to find the answer until I had finished writing the question. Hopefully this new question will help someone.